# How to attach base64 image in mail to JavaMail and MimeMessageHelper?

Tags: java, spring, email

I am trying to send the Mime email with an image attachment but do know how to do this. I tried the online solution but did not work. I will get the encoded image and need to decode and attach in the mail. This is my code

```
public class SendEmail{

public static void main( String[] args ) throws javax.mail.MessagingException, IOException
{  

    String value= "Wyk+HjAxHTAyNzg3MDUdODQwHTAxOR0wMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAd" +
            "RkRFQh0wMDAwMDAwHTA0MB0dMS8xHTUwLjVMQh1OHVcgMzR0aCBTdHJlZXQdQ" +
            "XVzdGluHVRYHSAeMDYdMTBaR0QwMDQdMTFaUmVjaXBpZW50IENvbXBhbnkgTmFt" +
            "ZR0xMlo5MDEyNjM3OTA2HTE0WioqVEVTVCBMQUJFTCAtIERPIE5PVCBTSElQKio" +
            "dMjNaTh0yMlocWR0yMFogHDAdMjZaNjEzMxwdHgQ=";     

      JavaMailSender mailSender = getJavaMailSender();

    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    MimeMessageHelper helper;
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    try{
        helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "utf-8");
        String sendTo = "abc@gmail.com";
        String htmlMsg = "<h1> hello </h1>";

        mimeMessage.setContent(htmlMsg, "text/html");

        // add attachment encode in base64
        byte[] decodedImg  Base64.decodeBase64(value);
        // dont know how to attache the decode img 


        helper.setTo(sendTo);
        helper.setSubject("Subject");
        mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
helper.addAttachment("MyImageName.jpg", new ByteArrayResource(value.getBytes()));
```

But please read:
From the code, it looks like you already encoded the image.
The "value" seems to be of Base64 format.
You should not deal with that as it is done for you.

```
// you can attach a file directly to the helper
FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File("image_file.jpg"));
helper.addAttachment("MyImageName.jpg", file);
```

If the attachment is not a file on your disk you can use this:

```
helper.addAttachment("MyImageName.jpg", new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(attachment)));
```

if this is an inputstream or this:

```
helper.addAttachment("MyImageName.jpg", new ByteArrayResource(value.getBytes()));
```

Comment: actually I will receive the base64 encoded image in the string.

Comment: After modifying the code by bellow code,my issue was solved. \n
value= value.replaceFirst("^data:image/[^;]*;base64,?", "");
byte[] bytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(value);
helper.addAttachment("MyImageName.jpg", new ByteArrayResource(bytes));

Answer (score 1):

Adding as attacment is already answered. Alternatively embedding the image works as follows:

```
htmlMsg += "<img width=\"400\" height=\"400\" "
    + "alt=\"View of the object.\" src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,"
    + value + "\">";
```

were value is the Base64 data, the mime type `image/jpeg` width and height must be adapted.

Some mail recipients may suppress rich text mails in favor of plain text, but as long as the `<img>` does not refer into the www (confirming you opened the e-mail), the rich text version is okay.

Answer (score 1):

After modifying the code by bellow code,my issue was solved.

```
value= value.replaceFirst("^data:image/[^;]*;base64,?", "");
byte[] bytes = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(value);
helper.addAttachment("MyImageName.jpg", new ByteArrayResource(bytes));
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the piece of code for sending base64 encoded string(image) as an attachment using java mail api.

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender emailSender;

public void sendMessageWithAttachment(String from,String replyTo, String to, String cc, String subject,  String emailContent, String base64EncodedString) {

MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);

helper.setFrom(from);
helper.setReplyTo(replyTo);
helper.setTo(to);
helper.setCc(cc);
helper.setSubject(subject);
helper.setText(emailContent, true);

// Use MimeDecoder for decoding in order to avoid illegal argument exception
byte[] imgBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(base64EncodedString);
ByteArrayDataSource dSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(imgBytes, "image/*");
helper.addAttachment("AttachedFile.jpg", dSource);
emailSender.send(message);

}
```